# Area of triangle formed by tangent to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and coordinate axes

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Using the Lagrange's multiplier we need to solve the following problem.

At what point of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ does the tangent line to it form with the coordinate axes a triangle of smallest area ?

I am stuck at the application of Lagrange's multiplier.  Had it been some other way like coordinate geometry, I could have managed somehow. But here I have no idea how to proceed. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you come up with an equation for the triangle area which we need to minimize?

Comment: @MathLover I really have no clue. I am trying my best :-(

Answer (score 2):

General tangent line to ellipse at point $(p,q)$ has equation

$$\frac{px}{a^2}+\frac{qy}{b^2}=1;\;\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{q^2}{b^2}=1$$

(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361183/the-instant-tangent), for instance.)

Suppose $p,q$ positive. (The problem is symmetric)

Triangle area is
$$A(p,q)=\frac{a^2b^2}{2pq};\;\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{q^2}{b^2}=1$$

Define
$$f(p,q,\lambda)=\frac{a^2b^2}{2pq}+\lambda\left(\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{q^2}{b^2}-1\right)$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{2 \lambda  p}{a^2}-\frac{a^2 b^2}{2 p^2 q}=0\\
\frac{2 \lambda  q}{b^2}-\frac{a^2 b^2}{2 p q^2}=0\\
\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{q^2}{b^2}=1\\
\end{cases}
$$

solution is $p=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}},q= \frac{b}{\sqrt{2}},\lambda=ab$.

Minimum area is
$$A(p,q)=ab$$

Because of the symmetry the points are four
$$\left(\pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}},\pm \frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

---

Hope this helps